# Display an onchange,updated page, for a selected value from a dropdown list using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page that display a dropdown list o user types.

After I choose a user type, a table of this users is displayed with a checkbox at every row.

When I check one of the users and hit the delete burron, the user is removed from the table.

Here is the main code of my HTML page:

```
<head>
<script>            
    function pop(str){
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200 ){                           
              document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
       }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","PendingUsersRequestsRefreshForm.php?q="+str,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <h2 align = "center">User Type:</h2>
    <select name="type" onchange="pop(this.value)">
    <option value="" >Select User Type</option>
    <?php
        $userType = $_POST['type'];
        foreach($userTypeList as $value){
            DrawSelectListElement($value,$userType); // a function that prints the user types ($userType is the default value to be shown at the dropdown list)
        }
        unset($value);
    ?>
    </select>
    <div id="ajax"> </div>
    <br><br><input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete Selected"> <br>            
</form>
```

And here is PendingUsersRequestsRefreshForm.php:

```
<?php
$conn = connectToDB();
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

if(strcasecmp($q, 'Student') == 0) { 
    echo "<br><h2>Pending Students Requests:<br></h2>";
    $sql = "SELECT uID AS 'User ID', CONCAT('Name: ',FirstName,' ', LastName,'<br>Phone: ',phoneNum,'<br>Mail:',email) AS 'User Details', faculty AS Faculty FROM users_requests WHERE userType = 'Student'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    printResultTableWithCheckbox($result,array(0)); // a function that prints the students table    
}

if(strcasecmp($q, 'Academic Advisor') == 0 ) {
    echo "<br><h2>Pending Advisor Requests:<br></h2>";
    $sql = "SELECT uID AS 'User ID', CONCAT('Name: ',FirstName,' ', engLastName,'<br>Phone: ',phoneNum,'<br>',email) AS 'User Details', faculty AS Faculty FROM users_requests WHERE userType = 'Academic Advisor'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    printResultTableWithCheckbox($result,array(0));
}

?>
```

After I select some users and hit delete, I want to see the updated table, but instead i see the page with only the select tab and without the updated table.

Can someone help me to figure out how can I see the updated table after such an action

Thanks!